# Counting the frequency distribution of letters in a text file

Tags: python-3.x

I'm writing a program that will count how many of each letter there are.

Currently, it's working but it counts upper and lower case letters separately. I tried to convert all of the characters to upper case but it didn't work.

```
myFile = open('textFile.txt', 'r+')
with open('textFile.txt', 'r') as fileinput:
   for line in fileinput:
       line = line.upper()
d = {}
for i in myFile.read():
    d[i] = d.get(i,0) + 1

for k,v in sorted(d.items()):
  print("{}: {}".format(k,v))
```

If my text file consists of:

abc
ABC

it will print:
(space) : 1
A: 1
B: 1
C: 1
a: 1
b: 1
c: 1

I would like it to print: 
A: 2
B: 2
C: 2

Answer (score 0):

the result of `line = line.upper()` is not used anywhere. Perhaps move the counting code into the block of code that performs the uppercase transformation. Then count the characters in each uppercased line.

Answer (score 0):

in this you are changing character to upper case but reading file only 
see line 4 , do somthing like this

```
 myFile = open('textFile.txt', 'r+')
with open('textFile.txt', 'r') as fileinput:
   for line in fileinput:
       line = line.upper()
d = {}
#change is here
for i in line:
    d[i] = d.get(i,0) + 1

for k,v in sorted(d.items()):
  print("{}: {}".format(k,v))
```

Answer (score 0):

This will do it.

```
chars = []
with open('textFile.txt', 'r') as fileinput:
   for line in fileinput:
       for c in line:
           chars.append(c.upper())
d = {}
for i in chars:
    d[i] = d.get(i, 0) + 1

for k,v in sorted(d.items()):
  print("{}: {}".format(k,v))
```

Or this:

```
d = {}

with open('textFile.txt', 'r') as fileinput:
    for line in fileinput:
        line = line.upper()
        for i in line:
            d[i] = d.get(i,0) + 1

for k,v in sorted(d.items()):
  print("{}: {}".format(k,v))
```

Comment: What is `myFile` for?

Comment: Copied it from the original code posted by Jake. I removed it.

Answer (score 0):

In Python, indenting is critical, you are converting the input to uppercase, but then throwing it away.

Try rearranging it like this:

```py
d = {}
#myFile = open('textFile.txt', 'r+') - removed as not needed due to "with" variant of file processing below.
with open('textFile.txt', 'r') as fileinput:
   for line in fileinput:
     line = line.upper()
     for i in line:
        d[i] = d.get(i,0) + 1

   for k,v in sorted(d.items()):
     print("{}: {}".format(k,v))
```

Comment: Eh, you are right - It is an oversight from re-arranging the original post! I will remove it... :-)